# Why does my Notepadqq editor does not recognize LAMP www folder and sub-folders?

Tags: php, file, ubuntu-18.04, lamp, editing

Attempting to get LAMP working on my 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I believe the set-up is close to correct. I have all Apache2, mysql, and PHP software installed. I have an index.php file located in folder /var/www/bookcorner directory which shows up as it should if I enter localhost/index.php in the browser address bar. This file may be edited in nano while saving the changes. However, I cannot use my editor Notepadqq (or presumably others) to edit the file.

Going through the file manager, I can select the file and open it in Notepadqq, but I cannot save it. I get the error, "folder does not exist". If I try a 'Save As' with Notepadqq, I do not see any folders past /var in the directory structure, though they obviously exist. The www folder and subfolders do not show up in Notepadqq.

There are three folders under /var/www which are

bookcorner
html
michaelsbookcorner.com

I have ownership of all of these folders

michaelsbookcorner.com is a live site at Infinityfree.net

I somehow got Apache2 to point to bookcorner for now which is fine. Eventually I would like to select between different websites but I only have one for now existing in another directory. I wish to begin utilizing LAMP rather than uploading PHP files to my hosting site all the time.

What settings/permissions/etc could I have missed here in order to get this working properly?

Comment: What settings do you have and how exactly are you invoking the editor? Things like users, file ownership, file permissions, possibly ACLs, they all make a difference. In any case, I don't see why the behaviour of a text editor is a programming question or deserves the "php". At most, I'd file a bug ticket, but Stack Overflow is also the wrong place for that. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I've subsequently managed to get VS Code working on this under-powered machine. This is much improved so the problem is resolved.